# Manage multiple branches with same codebase in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches in git. lets say branch1 and branch2.

Both branch contains same codebase but each branch differs with their graphic assets (like images, icons etc).

So now if I made a commit in branch1, I had to manually commit the same code in branch2 since merging branch1 in branch2 will result in conflict due to different images.

Is there any other way to maintain the same codebase across two branches without manual commit?

Comment: Keep your common codebase in a seperate git repo. And then symlink it at both the places with different graphic assets. ?

Comment: `with their graphic assets` ... hold it right there: binaries, such as images, don't play well with Git, and you might want to not even version them with Git.  With regard to your actual question, committing and merging/rebasing is how workflow works in Git, this is it.

Comment: @Soumya you mean just  pointing to respective assets on each branch. right?

Comment: @manikandankannan Sorry my bad, I read two seperate repos. Yes.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your reply. Rebasing in git refers to taking all commit in one branch and patching them in another branch. If that is so, then will that assets commit result in conflicts. right?

Comment: Do the two branches share any history?

Answer (score 0):

If your commit on branch1 contains only code,  you can checkout to branch2 and use

> ```
> git cherry-pick sha1_of_commit
> ```

Comment: Thanks Zildyan. I will check on that.